# jQuery setTimeout function doesn't work

Tags: settimeout, jquery

```
function zIndex(parcaNumber1, parcaNumber2, Timeout) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(parcaNumber1).css("z-index", "2");
        $(parcaNumber2).css("z-index", "1");
    }, Timeout);
}
```

I have a function, but does not work.
what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
function zIndex(parcaNumber1, parcaNumber2, Timeout) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('a'); //it's working
    }, Timeout);
}
```

probably you transfer parameters `parcaNumber1`, `parcaNumber2` as string, but call it like an object:
`$(parcaNumber1).css("z-index","2");`

try:
`$('.' + parcaNumber1).css("z-index","2");`
or 
`$('#' + parcaNumber1).css("z-index","2");`

Comment: @user1140926 so accept it as the correct answer (right symbol on the left)

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't know what you are trying to do, but check this out: I made a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGLe2/17/)**.

See if it's what you are looking for. Don't forget to set `div`s with `position: absolute;`

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="subtest"></div>
<input type="button" id="but" value="go" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#but").click(function(){
   zIndex('#test', '#subtest', 1000);
});


function zIndex(parcaNumber1, parcaNumber2, Timeout) {
 setTimeout(function () {
     $(parcaNumber1).css("z-index","2");
     $(parcaNumber2).css("z-index", "1");
 }, Timeout);
}
```